# Alternatives to JUpload for very large (> 2GB) files

Tags: file-upload, large-files

Our customers need to upload very large files (around 10GB or so) to our web-service.  Ignoring any server side complexities, what options exist for the client side?  JUpload seems to be the most common, but it's file selector is very unfriendly looking.  Our clients would be happy to install a browser extension, so it doesn't need to be limited to Java, and something that uses the native OS file selector would be preferred.  Browsers used by customers include the usual (IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome), but we may be able to limit clients to a particular browser, so something that is not cross-browser *may* be acceptable, but is certainly not preferred.

Comment: It is a little bit strange to upload 10GB files through a browser! There are ftp clients - it is faster and more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

We use https://transloadit.com/ for this purpose, but some web browsers may not support larger than 2GB files.